# Test for any connection Python Socket Module

Tags: python

Is there a way to check for a connection with the Python socket module?

```
while connection==True:
```

Something like that is what I am looking for, where connection is whatever the function would be for the module.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if a connection exist inside a try block like this :

```
import socket

def alive(host, port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        translate = socket.gethostbyname(host)
        test = s.connect_ex((translate, port))
        return test
    except socket.error:
        return 1

test=alive(host,port)
if test ==0:
    print "success"
else:
    print "error"
```